# CentOS 7 syslog server

Tags: centos, syslog, rsyslog

I have a CentOS 7 server that collects syslogs form all the Cisco equipment. I went to setup a second syslog server for redundancy. I have set everything up but I cannot seem to get the new server to accept syslogs form across the network. If I use the "logger" command I can write info to the syslog so long as I run logger locally. If I run it from a different server the messages don't get written to the syslog. It seems that syslog works locally, but not when something send to it remotely. The rsyslog.conf file is exactly the same on the other server that works. I have good connectivity to the new server, and I disabled SElinux. I'm not sure if anyone is familiar with this issue. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should check your firewall rules on the new server to allow tcp/udp port 514

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I forgot about  the firewall. That was it!

Comment: Remember to re-enable SELinux.